# In python while executing shell command pass sting which contains quotes

Tags: python, linux, shell

I want to execute a shell command like this
`/usr/bin/sudo su tunnel -c "/usr/bin/ssh tunnel@peer /usr/bin/sudo /srv/bin/ops -o shell-ops set_ntp '{\\\"abc\\\":{\\\"xyz\\\":true}}'"`

I am not able to achieve it

````
payload_str = json.dumps(payload).replace('"', '\"')
cmd = r"/usr/bin/ssh tunnel@peer /usr/bin/sudo /srv/bin/ops -o shell-ops set_ntp '%s'" %payload_str
check_output(["/usr/bin/sudo", "su", "tunnel", "-c", cmd])```
````

The error which I get it

`TypeError: set_ntp() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`
`set_ntp` take only one argument which should be a json string.

Comment: Note that `cmd` includes an ssh command, and check_output also includes an ssh command.  I believe you want to remove the 5th element of the check_output list and replace it with cmd.

Comment: Opiniated: using `sudo su` with an ssh tunnel calling another `sudo` command inside a Python program, just sounds awful (and a potential security risk).

Comment: You are right it may be awful but the does not solve the issue. Using sudo or not sudo its another thing the issue how do I properly pass it

Comment: What's the point of the "sudo su ha-tunnel"?  ssh does not require special permissions to run.  Is it just to gain access to a private key?  Surely there are better ways.

Comment: The function `.replace('"','\"')` does absolutely nothing.  It replaces double-quotes with double-quotes.  You need `.replace('"','\\"')`.

Comment: I need sudo for su, Also I have tried your suggestion it does not work